# WebService Soap Response in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, soap

I am new to web services so please help me to sort out my issue. I have a requirement to create a web service in C#. This web service will return the soap response.

my webservice should send response as a soap message, Is there any exmple of client and server which send an receive soap message , it is a non wcf webservice i tried with msdn but cant grab it.

thanks for any help....

Answer (score 1):

You can try Fiddler or SOAPUI tool.

Using Fiddler, You can issue requests and get response from your Webservices locally.

Very efficient for testing your webservices locally on your m/c.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service  as an  "ASP.Net Website" project in visual studio. Then you can add .asmx (web service code behind file) to your project. You can define your web methods in asmx file which may return xml as response. Then you have to publish and host the web service in IIS.

In client side project, you can add the reference to the webservice by using "Add Service reference" option in visual studio that will generate classes through which you can access your web service. Then you can call your web methods through those classes.

when you are adding service reference in client side, you have to give the url of the wsdl file of your web service to locate it.